# The debugger can not continue running the process InstallShield Limited Edition error

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013, installshield-le

I have created a small application in vb.net (vs 2013). When i want to make installer file through InstallShield Limited Edition, after click on Attach it show some error message. like this

[image]

My vb.net project contain single winform. Can anyone tell me why this is happened?

Comment: Have you set your vb.net project as the 'startup project' (right click on it in Solution Explorer)?

Comment: I cant understand. Can you describe me what you have told? May be i have not done this yet. Thats why this error occurred.